# How to use Select in dynamic list?

Tags: c#, list, linq, select, dynamic

I have dynamic models in my dynamic list. attributes.blabla exist on
all my models.

```
        dynamic reqList= new List<dynamic>();
        
        //filled this list

        List<string> blablaList = reqList.Select(x => x.attributes.blabla).ToList();
```

[I am taking this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cvVtm.png)

How can i take attributes.blabla as string list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main point is that `reqList` is not IEnumerable in your code. Just change the signature to List of dynamics.

```
List<dynamic> reqList= new List<dynamic>();
reqList.Add(new{ attributes = new{blabla = "qq"}});

List<string> blablaList = reqList.Select(x => x.attributes.blabla as string).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change `dynamic reqList= new List<dynamic>();` to `List<dynamic> reqList= new List<dynamic>();`
In `dynamic` object, the method binding is being done at runtime, not at compile time. You have to cast the list items like this:

```
List<string> blablaList = reqList.Select(x => x.attributes.blabla).Cast<string>().ToList();
```

More about `dynamic` - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/using-type-dynamic

Comment: The error still here, because reqList is not an IEnumerable in the author's sample, so the delegate type could not be inferred for Select method of dynamic type